# Палиндром с простым числом

Tags: c, алгоритм, рефакторинг

Суть задания написать наибольший простой палиндром не больше N.
У меня есть код, но он работает до определенных чисел, а именно после 1900 он всегда выдает 1, где ошибка? Microsoft Visual studio

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int n;              
int con = 0;      
int h;
int d;
int schet = 0;
scanf_s("%d", &h);
if (h <= 100) { // костыль для 100
    printf("%d", 1);
}
for (n = 1; n <= h; n++)
{
    for (d = 2; d < (h / 2); d++)
    {
        if (n % d == 0)
        {
            schet = schet + 1;
        }
    }

    if (schet == 0)
    {                                       //палиндром 
        int reverse = 0;
        int golov = n;

        while (golov != 0)
        {
            reverse = reverse * 10;
            reverse = reverse + golov % 10;
            golov = golov / 10;
        }
        if (n == reverse)
        {
            con = n;
        }
    }
    schet = 0;
 }
 printf("%d", con);

 }
```

Comment: Хорошо, что Вы стараетесь, но учитесь называть переменные в соответствии с их назначением. Смысл операций в Вашем коде крайне сложно понять.

Comment: почему не сделать две отдельных функции, одна из которых будет проверять на простоту, а вторая на палиндром?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>schet обнуляйте на каждой итерации внешнего цикла.</del> Пардон, увидел обнуление в конце.

Кроме того, внешний цикл разумно запустить в обратную сторону и останавливаться после первого найденного палиндрома.

И поиск простых нужно останавливать, когда делитель попался, да и искать лучше до достижения условия  `d * d < n` - заметьте, что у вас там вообще h использовалось - запутались в своих непонятных переменных, как вам в комментариях подсказали.

```
for (n = h; n > 100; n--)
{
    schet = 0;
    for (d = 2; d*d < n; d++)
    {
        if (n % d == 0)
        {
            schet = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (schet == 0)
    {                                       //палиндром 
        int reverse = 0;
        int golov = n;

        while (golov != 0)
        {
            reverse = reverse * 10;
            reverse = reverse + golov % 10;
            golov = golov / 10;
        }
        if (n == reverse)
        {
            con = n;
            break;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: И как это правильно сделать? я просто нубик

Comment: Да именно так, как я подсказал. Код подправил прямо здесь, не проверял. Используйте отладку, если что.

Comment: Ну как, получилось?

Comment: Все еще пытаюсь осилить, откладку пробовал.... :(

Comment: Да  всё работает, если обнуление счётчика правильно записать, у меня было == https://ideone.com/ZyL6kD

Comment: Спасибо, меня уже поплавило и не заметил, что оно верно работает